# How is "Posturing" used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, nouns

Charles Murray tweeted this a few weeks ago:

**@charlesmurray: People who despise Trump (like me) need to be thinking through this issue. Thinking, analyzing, not posturing. https://t.co/jBBfEtBI4L**

And added a link to this article, which is present here.

I've looked up posturing and it refers to me posture, which tells me that it's more about stance and behavior.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "Posturing" is exactly what you see Trump doing.

Comment: Posturing is claiming that one has more experience, better education, more money, a bigger penis, a more realistic take on reality, than the opponent, who is inexperienced, benighted, broke, poorly hung, and living in a fantasy world of his own device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its meaning is well-defined in the dictionary. For example, "[posture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/posture)" as a verb means:

> to assume an artificial or ***pretended attitude*** :  attitudinize

[Merriam-Webster]

However, in your example, the definition of [Urban Dictionary] might explain the [meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Posture) better.

> Taking a position of defense whether verbally or physically. 'She
>   started posturing when her definition of hip-hop was disputed.'

In my opinion, Charles Murray meant "people should take more proactive (aggressive, if you will) attitudes towards Trump's remarks than just sit there and listen to them (defensively without thinking).

Answer (score 2):

"Posturing" in this case has the sense of behaving "in a way that's intended to impress or mislead others."—OED

It's taking a position or stance—adopting a "posture", if you like—in a figurative sense.